# switch preference taking a long time to switch

Tags: android

I have a android switch in my app that hides the icon in the app draw. The problem is it takes a long time to hide and to enable.

```
public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.drawer_icon);

            PreferenceManager preferenceManager = getPreferenceManager();
            if (preferenceManager.getSharedPreferences().getBoolean("drawer_icon", true)) {
                PackageManager p = getActivity().getPackageManager();
                ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getActivity(), com.dfuse.brokenswitcher.LaunchIconActivity.class);
                p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
            } else {
                int newState;
                newState = PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED;
                PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
                pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(getActivity(), LaunchIconActivity.class), newState, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        }


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is "long time"? A minute? An hour? What is the expected time?

Comment: It takes about a minute or two

Comment: How long do you expect it to take?

Comment: Right away , I have seen other app where it happens right away.

Comment: Have you used the debugger with break points?